# Sending an XMPP message to a large number of users

Tags: xmpp

I'm interested in sending "system status update" to a kind-of-large amount of users (say in the thousands or so, for the sake of discussion) over XMPP. The recipients would be completely arbitrary XMPP accounts spread over various domains, rather than being on one server/domain or anything like that.

Is there a good way to do so such "broadcasting", or will I have to resort to sending an individual message to each individual recipient? If I have to do the latter, is it likely or unlikely that such practices will be frowned upon by server operators? I'm not planning to send a lot of these messages; hardly even once per day.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16527462/1454048) recommends a good pub-sub approach, that might be the best way to accomplish what you're doing.

Comment: XMPP PubSub is the way to go.